# Meta decorator with parameters, defined in explicit functions

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, idioms

I want an explicit replacement for a common decorator idiom.

There is a clever one-line decorator that has been [copy-pasted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming) without explanation in many code bases for many years:

```python
decorator_with_args = lambda decorator: lambda *args, **kwargs: lambda func: decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)
```

My problem with this is precisely [that it is clever](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25284): it explains nothing about what it does, has many moving parts that are not named, it is non-obvious and lacks expressiveness.

Even the [widely-cited ActiveState recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/465427-simple-decorator-with-arguments/) by Peter Hunt from 2005 gives no clue as to what this is doing internally nor what the names of its parts should be.

I would like to see a more Pythonic, more explicit and expressive replacement with its component parts easily understood.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't quite know how the details of the original are meant to work, I may have this wrong:

```python
import functools

def decorator_with_arguments(decorator):
    """ Wrap a decorator, allowing it to accept arbitrary arguments. """

    @functools.wraps(decorator)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """ The resulting decorator that accepts arbitrary arguments. """

        def _function(func):
            """ Invoke the original decorator with the arguments. """
            return decorator(func, *args, **kwargs)

        return _function

    return wrapper
```

Please suggest better names for these parts, and point out any bugs (i.e. different behaviour from the original).